# How to adjust silverlight chart animation speed?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, charts

I have a pie chart I am using from the silverlight toolkit with the animation sequence being first to last. The one thing I have noticed is that the animation between each slice appearing is a little slow for what I am needing. I am having trouble figuring out how to adjust the speed of each slice appearing. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

```
<toolkit:Chart x:Name="charttest" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Title="" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"> 
                            <toolkit:PieSeries x:Name="pie" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource PieDataPointStyleTest}" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast"/>
                        </toolkit:Chart>
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
<toolkit:Chart x:Name="charttest" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Title="" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"> 
                            <toolkit:PieSeries x:Name="pie" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.01"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </toolkit:PieSeries>
                        </toolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: Can you post the XAML or the code behind?

Comment: Add xaml or cs with animation.

Comment: This [blog post](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd433476) tells you everything (and I do mean *everything* about the toolkit chart and how to modify things using Blend. There might be something useful in it.

Comment: I actually was reading that blog post earlier, but still couldn't figure out how to adjust the animation speed.

Comment: Admittedly I just skimmed, but it goes into editing the template to affect the appearance etc. You should be able to get hold of the template in code and modify it there.